# How to Select record which are not in foreign key table using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I got following entities

```
1. tbl_city

    City_id pk AI

    City_name    

2. tbl_area

    area_id pk

    area_name

    city_id fk tbl_city(city_id)

3. tbl_restaurant

   restaurant_id pk 

   restaurant_name


4. tbl_restaurant_areas

   restaurant_area_id pk

   area_id fk tbl_area(area_id)

   restaurant_id fk tbl_restaurant(restauran_id)
```

Now i got one method which accepts two parameters `city_id` and `restaurant_id` which supposed to select areas from `tbl_area` which are not present in `tbl_restaurant_areas`. My LINQ query looks like below

```
from a in ctx.tbl_areas where a.city_id==city_id && !ctx.tbl_restaurant_areas
            .Any(ra => (ra.area_id==a.area_id) && ra.reastaurant_id==restaurant_id)
            select new {a};
```

Comment: A left outer join should help which give the items in one list that are not in the 2nd list : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: *My LINQ query looks like below* - Well, great, but what's wrong with it?